# Detailed explanations on OWASP Zap Security scan rules

Tags: proxy, csrf, zap

As an example, I have installed Anti-CSRF Scanning rule in ZAP proxy and scanned a POST request which does not verify the CSRF token value from the back end. Ideally, it is a CSRF vulnerability, but ZAP proxy scanner did not detect that. I am wondering whether I have done the scan correctly, but could not find any place to verify the configuration.

Can someone help me out?

---

Anti-CSRF Rule
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First check that ZAP actually made the POST request. Its always easier to use the desktop rather than daemon mode when debugging these sort of problems. So start ZAP in desktop mode, explore your app in the same way as before and then check that the POST request is in the Sites tree.

If it is not in the Sites tree then ZAP wont attack it. Exploring your app effectively is key to testing it effectively. If its not been found then there are various options available which we cover if thats the case.

Comment: I am not using daemon mode. I am using desktop mode. however, I found that in this article, https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/active-scan-rules-beta/ 
Anti-CSRF token verification will happen only in the UI layer (just check whether each form has csrf token or not) and it is not actually validating whether Anti-CSRF verification happens from the backend. is there a way I can make that happens also?

Comment: No, that rules does perform requests to see if the token appears to be used. We have another rule https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/passive-scan-rules/#csrf-countermeasures which is a passive rule and just checks to see if tokens are used.

Comment: I attached a screenshot f the active rule I am talking about. I simply captured a post request via proxy and ran above anti csrf token check to see whether it shows any issues with my POST request. unfortunately, I didn't receive any result. however in that post request actually CSRF validation is not enforced from the backend. any idea why this happened? am I doing something wrong? let me add the post request I captured through owasp proxy.

Comment: Request ->


**POST https://<domain>/training/addCourse HTTP/1.1**


CSRF parameter sent in the request body ->


**addCourse[_csrf_token]=XX**

Comment: Did you proxy the initial GET request which generates the anti CSRF token through ZAP as well? If not then ZAP wont know where it came from.

Comment: Yes, I did. We don't have a specific endpoint to generate CSRF token values. In our application when we request for a web page, from the backend (via PHP) it generates a car token and embeds it into the form, then send as HTML response to the client. That is what happens.
but one thing, HTML form to form CSRF token id differs. can that be a problem?

Comment: Embedding a CSRF token in the form is the usual approach - so I'm asking if you have made a GET request to the page that form is on. FYI you'll get quicker responses on the ZAP user Group ;) https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: Yes I did. I made get request first. @simon. thanks for pointing me out the google group :)